# Magic quote and mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, slash

Here is the original code:

```
       if (($handle = fopen($source_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $columns = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",");
    foreach ($columns as &$column) {
        $column = str_replace(".","",$column);
    }
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        while(count($data) < count($columns)) {
            array_push($data, NULL);
        }
        $c = count($data);
        for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
            $data[$i] = "'{$data[$i]}'";
        }

        $sql[] = '(' . implode(',', $data) . ", '" . $_POST['custgroup'] . "'," . $_POST['user_id'] . ')';
    }


$query = "INSERT INTO $target_table (" . implode(',', $columns) . 
      ',custgroup,user_id) VALUES ' . implode(',', $sql);


    //mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
    echo $query;
    fclose($handle);
}
```

But once I added mysql_real_escape_string:

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO $target_table (" . implode(',',array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $columns)) . 
          ',custgroup,user_id) VALUES ' . implode(',',array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $sql));
```

The query will become :

`INSERT INTO UserAddedRecord (lastname,firstname,ceLL,fax,email,code,custgroup,user_id) VALUES (\'Last\',\'First\',\'01122331\',\'\',\'abc@hotmail.com\',\'12345\', \'\',17)`

I checked my php.ini and get_magic_quotes_gpc(),magic quote is disabled.

magic_quotes_gpc = Off

magic_quotes_runtime = Off

magic_quotes_sybase = Off

What should be the problem?or I should just apply stripslashes()?But I assume it will be used only when magic quote is enabled.

Comment: What's in `$columns` and `$sql`? Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: You are using PHP and mysql, but you are not using PDO. why is that?

Comment: @MattEllen I tried , but get errors because I'm not so familiar with PDO when using implode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should to something along the lines of:

- use `mysql_real_escape_string` on all string values
- cast all the interters to (int)
- **after** that apply the surrounding single quotes ( ' )

The point of mysql_real_escape_string is to escape the special chars within your test content so using stripslashes would take that away.

Another way to solve that is to look into [`preparedStatements`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php) where you don't need to to client side esacping.

**Just remember that the whole point of doing this is to prevent [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection) and act accordingly :)**

Comment: Thankyou edorian , I tried preparedStatements before but end up with errors , now I try again and it seems works . Thanks again .